# Calculating the Absorbed Heat & the Change in Internal Energy of an undefined thermodynamic process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

[image: Cyclic thermodynamic process]

In the given figure of a P-V diagram, the process from $T_2$ from $T_3$ (the hypotenuse part of the triangle) doesn't follow any of the 4 thermodynamic processes (i.e Isothermal, Isochoric, Isobaric, Adiabatic processes). The given system is of a gas (which is not necessarily an Ideal Gas) contained in a metal container having a frictionless piston.

The volume of the gas can be changed by moving the piston back and forth & the temperature of the gas can be changed by exchanging heat with its surroundings through the metal container. The question asks to find the absorbed heat & the change in internal energy of the system as the temperature of the system changes from $T_2$ to $T_3$ (the hypotenuse).

I couldn't find a satisfactory answer of what formulae should be used here even after searching in my textbooks. My friends said that we can use the "$du=nC_v(T_3-T_2)$" formula here for calculating the change in internal energy & the "$dQ=nC_v(T_3-T_2)+ \frac{1}{2}(P_1+P_2)(V_2-V_1)$" formula for calculating the absorbed heat in this process. But, why should we use these formulae here as this process is not a defined thermodynamic process & only a theoretical one? Is there any explanation as to why we should be using these formulae here? Can we even calculate the change in internal energy & the absorbed heat for this process (temperature going from $T_2$ to $T_3$)? If yes then kindly explain how.

I'm a high school junior & have not taken any Thermodynamics course, so a lot of things are yet unknown to me. It would be delightful for me if anyone would clear my doubts & provide a lucid explanation to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Promoted from a comment by [Chet MIller]:

> The equation for the work is correct, irrespective of whether it is an
> ideal gas or not. But, for an ideal gas (whose internal energy depends
> only on temperature), ΔU=nCvΔT. If it's not an ideal gas, then the
> internal energy can depend on both temperature and pressure (or
> specific volume), so there is not enough information provided for a
> non-ideal gas.